# Debugging tools for Android apps

Tags: android, http, debugging

i am currently developing an Android app with AndroidStudio.
Now i got a wierd issue, where the app crashes and just ends itself without any exception or something. (Yes i got every method wrapped in a try-catch block)
The issue happens somewhere in between these lines:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://" + JSON.webString + ":" + JSON.webPort +  "/path/file.php");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

So i need a way to see the cause of the crash or any kind of error message i can work with.
I know in Delphi there´s a tool called EurekaLog which does exactly that. Is there something like this for Android?
I have heared about google play console but i am not sure if this will solve my problem.

Hope you guys can help me and suggest some good software.

Comment: Run adb logcat.  That prints the system log, and it will have the full stack trace.

Comment: I will definitely check my logcat. But is there a way to get bug reports from the app that is running on the devices of my costumers?

Comment: Here´s my logcat Exception:
`java.util.NoSuchElementException: Death link does not exist`
but i couldn't find anything useful online

Comment: The full stack trace for things like that help, it has class names and line numbers.  Never seen that error myself, so I have no further help unfortunately.  As for crashes on customer machines-  play store has some functionality like that, as do 3rd party offerings like crashlytics.  They are all far from 100% of course.